# How do three electrons entangle with each other?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement, superposition

In a Quantum entity of two electrons entangled to each other, we know that when one electron's spin is known, then the other electron's spin is the opposite.

But, What's the case in a quantum entity that involves 3 electrons entangled to each other ?

I have two questions about this

> 1. How does the information of spin is shared across three electrons since there are only two
>    states of spin that is up and down ?
> 2. What do we know about other two electrons' spin when we know the spin of one electron ?

Comment: "In a Quantum entity of two electrons entangled to each other, we know that when one electron's spin is known, then the other electron's spin is just the opposite." This is a entangled state, not the only entangled state. Another state for example is if they have the same spin. The point is if they are entangled you cant describe one without the other.

Comment: @shaihorowitz But I have heard many scientists describe that when one electron's spin is found to be up, then the other must be down.

Comment: This applies to entangled electrons sharing the same spatial wavefunction(e.g in atomic orbitals)

Comment: @shaihorowitz And also how does that quantum entity be in superposition if both have the same spin.

Comment: What other quantum numbers are present? Note that if the only thing differentiating the electrons is spin then you can only have 2 electrons in the system since they are Fermions.

Answer (score 3):

Entanglement of a quantum state $|\Psi\rangle$ that has two subsystems 1 and 2 is defined as any state that cannot be decomposed in the form
$$|\Psi\rangle=|\psi\rangle_1\otimes|\phi\rangle_2$$ for some subsystem states $|\psi\rangle_1$ and $|\phi\rangle_2$.
Entanglement can manifest in many ways, one of which is a particular state
$$\frac{|\uparrow\rangle_1\otimes|\downarrow\rangle_2-|\downarrow\rangle_1\otimes|\uparrow\rangle_2}{\sqrt{2}},$$
in which any measurement of the spin of states 1 and 2 in the same basis will have exactly anticorrelated results, as mentioned in the question. However, not all entangled states have that property: another exemplary entangled state is $$\frac{|\uparrow\rangle_1\otimes|\uparrow\rangle_2-|\downarrow\rangle_1\otimes|\downarrow\rangle_2}{\sqrt{2}};$$ this state will have highly *correlated* spin-measurement results, not highly *anticorrelated* results.
Given that example, it is straightforward to extend to a "GHZ-type" entangled state of three spins:
$$\frac{|\uparrow\rangle_1\otimes|\uparrow\rangle_2\otimes|\uparrow\rangle_3-|\downarrow\rangle_1\otimes|\downarrow\rangle_2\otimes|\downarrow\rangle_3}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

Now, to answer your exact question in the title, how can one make this state that has three entangled electron spins? One route is by using an "entangling gate" such as the CNOT gate, which does a different operation on the spin of subsystem 2 depending on the spin of subsystem 1. For example, a CNOT gate acting on systems 1 and 2 will perform the operation
$$\mathrm{CNOT}_{12}\left(\frac{|\uparrow\rangle_1+|\downarrow\rangle_1}{\sqrt{2}}\otimes|\downarrow\rangle_2\right)=\frac{|\uparrow\rangle_1\otimes|\uparrow\rangle_2+|\downarrow\rangle_1\otimes|\downarrow\rangle_2}{\sqrt{2}};$$ an entangled state has been generated from a separable state. Performing the same operation after adding a third subsystem, we find
$$\mathrm{CNOT}_{13}\left(\frac{|\uparrow\rangle_1\otimes|\uparrow\rangle_2+|\downarrow\rangle_1\otimes|\downarrow\rangle_2}{\sqrt{2}}\otimes|\downarrow\rangle_3\right)=\frac{|\uparrow\rangle_1\otimes|\uparrow\rangle_2\otimes|\uparrow\rangle_3+|\downarrow\rangle_1\otimes|\downarrow\rangle_2\otimes|\downarrow\rangle_3}{\sqrt{2}}.$$ So this CNOT gate can be used to take separable states to entangled ones. The physical implementation of such entangling operations is one of the goals of quantum computing, and is possible with a variety of different physical systems.

Comment: @user13608097 If you need an answer thats in between the level of my first comment and this answer let me know and i'll add one. This is a good high level answer if you can understand the notation.

Comment: @shaihorowitz You could still post the answer anyway.

Comment: @shaihorowitz Yeah this is a good answer though I can understand it partially. I couldn't understand the notations since I have studied only the theory. So can you post an answer that does not involve notations and also explain how to interpret the statement scientists say "when one electron's spin is found to be up, then the other must be down" and explaining my two questions "how?" or maybe why the questions are irrelevant if that's the case ?