# How one can arrange three entangled electrons?

Tags: quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement

In the atom, electrons are entangled by their spin. The electrons are bound to the nucleus and the electrical repulsion between them is weakened. It is by nature that they arrange themselves as observed and expressed by the Paulis exclusion principle.

In this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/652330/how-do-three-electrons-entangle-with-each-other) the theoretical result of an entanglement of three electrons is described. Are these free electrons? I assume not, because the electric field will repel them from each other and far drown out the effect of spin.

How one can arrange three entangled electrons?

Comment: Other types of qubits may be much more readily entangled that electron spins because of the high degree of control in, say, superconducting qubits

Comment: @QuantumMechanic What are superconducting qubits? Made from? Arrangement?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconducting_quantum_computing lists phase qubits, charge qubits, and flux qubits. These are two-level systems that behave mathematically like electron spins but that are not as challenging to manipulate independently

Answer (score 0):

The answer that you link to is in the context of entangled states in a quantum computer. The entangled states that can be prepared and manipulated in a quantum computer are not necessarily electron spin states (as pointed out in comments to your question). Electron spin states are often used to illustrate the concepts behind quantum computing because they are easier to understand and conceptualise than other quantum states. But a variety of different quantum computer technologies are available.

Even where states are realised as the spin of electrons, these electrons will not be orbiting the same atom - at an atomic scale, they will be widely separated.

One of the (many) technical challenges in designing a quantum computer is preventing entangled states from decohering for long enough to carry out a useful number of operations on them (the size of “useful” depends on the complexity of the algorithms that you want to run). But the challenge is to prevent entangled states from interacting with the surrounding environment, not within themselves.